# Check for specific character between two characters

Tags: c#, string

To illustrate:
Take the input string `"Yesterday I ate two bu rgers"` (space intentional)

I want to check the input string to see if a space (or any other pre-defined character) `" "` exists between the two characters (in this case) `"u"` and `"r"`. And if it exists delete this character.

First I came up with this:

```cs
string someString = "Yesterday I ate two bu rgers";
string charA = 'u', charB = 'r';
if (someString.Contains(charA) &&
 someString.Substring(someString.IndexOf(charA) + 1).Equals(" ") &&
 someString.Substring(someString.IndexOf(charA) + 2).Equals(charB))
    //delete the space
```

However not only does this feel (and look) inefficient as heck, It also fails if the sentence would be "Yesterday you ate two bu rgers" since it will take the index of the first "u". So I would have to do an additional check for multiple instances of `charA`

Another solution I thought of is to split the sentence on every space, and see if the last character of the split matches `charA` and the first character of the next split matches `charB`. And if it does join the two together.

```cs
string[] splitString = someString.Split(null);
for (int i = 0; i < splitString.Length -1; i++)
{
    string lastChar =  splitString[i].Substring(splitString[i].Length - 1);
    string firstChar = splitString[i + 1].Substring(0, 1);

    if(lastChar.Equals(charA) && firstChar.Equals(charB))
    {
        string joined = splitString[i] + splitString[i + 1]; 
    }
}
```

However this method is also flawed as it breaks when i.e two spaces are present in the input.

Is there a way to do this without needing a bunch of if statements or loops? (unless there really is no other way I would really like to *not* use regex)

Comment: Why you don't want to make use of a Regex ?

Comment: `input.Replace("u r", "ur");`? Or `input.Replace($"{charA} {charB}", "{charA}{charB});`?

Comment: @Christos As it is I have little knowledge of regex. And although I am willing to learn it, it would mean I put in code i'm unable to manage/update myself until I do. Which I prefer not to do. Though as I said I can use it if that really is the solution.

Comment: Space between y I are also considered?

Comment: What would you expect to happen with the sentence _"Yesterday yo**u r**eally liked your two bu rgers"_? Without implementing an actual dictionary of accepted words, it will always be possible to create sentences that are not parsed correctly.

Comment: @oerkelens I am working on a (limited) set of words in a dictionary I'm cross checking against to prevent that as much as possible. And not working with complete sentences as in the example which reduces the chances. It is indeed still something I have to watch out for.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed That's an amazing suggestion I have completely overlooked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string is an array of characters. Loop through it and inspect the characters.

```
for (int i = 2; i < someString.Length; i++) {
    if (someString[i] == charB && someString[i - 2] == charA) {
        //TODO: delete the char in between.
        break;
    }
}
```

If you start at index = 2 and test for the second character, you can simply go back by 2 positions to inspect the first one.

But of course you could also look ahead like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < someString.Length - 2; i++) {
    if (someString[i] == charA && someString[i + 2] == charB) {
        //TODO: delete the char in between.
        break;
    }
}
```